# Libxml2 for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, libxml2, c++-cx

I am trying to build libxml2 to the Windows Phone platform. However, I am facing some issues with the libxml2 threads (the windows threads are not available for Windows Phone). Someone knows how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this blog post from Shawn Hargreaves: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2012/03/12/createthread-for-windows-8-metro.aspx

As you stated Windows Phone 8 can not access the Win32 CreateThread API, but you can write a CreateThread shim that uses the WinRT ThreadPool API to create threads.